# google calendar unable to delete event by id

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

So i have a apps script code that creates events as such:

```
var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
var start = new Date(startDt);
var end = new Date(endDt); 
var event = cal.createEvent(title, start, end, {
 description : desc,
});
```

and it works fine, after it creates the event, i use

```
event.getId()
```

to log the event id

When i run the following code in order to delete an event using the id i logged, it tells me that event doesn't exist.

```
var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
var event = cal.getEventSeriesById(evc2);
event.deleteEventSeries();
return;
```

why is it unable to find the event? 
is the code i use to log the event id incorrect?

or is the way i'm trying to delete an event incorrect?

Comment: I looked at the documentation, and it seems like your code should work.

Comment: You did not mention where you get the `evc2` variable. Are you sure that is a valid Event Series ID? I did a quick test where I have the script create an event, store it's ID in a variable and then used `deleteEventSeries()` to delete the event with that ID and it worked fine

Comment: what i've posted is an abstract, so evc2 was defined elsewhere, i've just tried a simplified version and indeed it work, so it seems i've done something that modifies evc2. i'll look thru my code again and keep you guys updated if i find something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the code works when i run it alone, so the problem is somewhere else.
after doing some cleanup and removing unused variables, it started working again.  I couldn't figure out where the problem was, but it's working now, thanks for the inputs